# QuickSight analysis is breaking when pointing to correct dataset and fields exists as it is after migration from Dev to Prod

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Need help,
QuickSight analysis is breaking when pointing to correct dataset that connected initially and fields exists as well after updation of dataset (spice)

The analysis (including filters) should not break if the analysis is pointing to dataset (that is working properly) and the fields that used initially still exists.